# Access nested options dialog in EnvDTE

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, envdte, visual-studio-macros, visual-studio-automation

I'm trying to use EnvDTE to change a Visual Studio option.

The EnvDTE object exposes the Properties collection to do this, and for example, to access the options exposed in the VS configuration dialog under Text Editor -> XML, one has to use `Properties("TextEditor", "XML")`.

This can be easily tested using PowerShell from the NuGet console, which exposes a `$dte` variable, for example this will show line numbers in XML files:

```
$dte.Properties("TextEditor", "XML").Item("ShowLineNumbers").Value = $true
```

My problem is that I cannot find where are the options listed in the submenu Text Editor -> XML -> Formatting. I tried

```
$dte.Properties("TextEditor", "XML - Formatting")
```

after looking at [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awdwz11a.aspx), but it does not work.

Comment: any update on this issue? how did you resolve this? i want to access TextEditor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> 1 intellesense property